# Change size of pantheon terminal

Tags: terminal, elementary-os

I haven't found any settings with regard to terminal size and I hate to keep resizing every time I want to use it.

How can I change the size of the terminal?

Comment: Not familiar with Pantheon specifically, but many X applications support the `-geometry` (yes, that's a single dash) command line switch. Try something like `$PANTHEON -geometry 160x50` and see if it does what you want.

Comment: hello @MichaelKjörling the said command won't work cause you do not target Pantheon Terminal specifically.

Comment: That comment does not make any sense to me. If the pantheon executable is named `pantheon` (which I don't know whether it is or not), you'd give the command `pantheon -geometry 160x50` which would probably open a new terminal window. Is that terminal window a different size than one opened by default?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `dconf-editor` you can navigate to:

> org.pantheon.terminal.settings

There are options for `window-height` and `window-width`.
I had the same problem and found the solution [here](https://gist.github.com/davidgomes/5162998).